# consolibyte sdk add item

Tags: php, xml, quickbooks

I am trying to add an item to quickbooks online using the Keith Palmer/Consolibyte sdk.  I have based my example on the example provided in the sdk however it appears that there is not enough information in the sdk version so the 'add item' fails.  Looking through the documentation from intuit it appears that I need to add a couple of extra fields.  However when I add them they are simply ignored by the sdk and not added into the xml passed to quickbooks.

```
<?php

$ItemService = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_Item();
$Item = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Item();

$Item->setName('My 1st Item');
$Item->setIncomeAccountRef('66');
$Item->setExpenseAccountRef('67');
$Item->setAssetAccountRef('65');
$Item->setType('Inventory');

$Item->setTrackQtyOnHand = ('true');        //MISSING FROM XML OUTPUT
$Item->setQtyOnHand = ('10');               //MISSING FROM XML OUTPUT
$Item->setInvStartDate = ('2015-01-01');    //MISSING FROM XML OUTPUT

if ($resp = $ItemService->add($Context, $realm, $Item))
{
print('Our new Item ID is: [' . $resp . ']');
}
else
{
print($ItemService->lastError($Context));
print("\n\n\n\n");

print('REQUEST: <code>' . htmlspecialchars($ItemService->lastRequest()) . '</code><br><br><br>');
print("\n\n\n\n");
print('RESPONSE: <code>' .     htmlspecialchars($ItemService->lastResponse()) . '</code><br><br><br>');

}


print('<br><br><br><br>');
print("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
print('Request [' . $IPP->lastRequest() . ']');
print("\n\n\n\n");
print('Response [' . $IPP->lastResponse() . ']');
print("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");

?>

</pre>

<?php

require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/views/footer.tpl.php';
```

If I manually add the items to the XML and enter into the API Explorer then it works as expected so the issue seems to be getting the required extras into the xml.

Here is the xml output from my code above:

```
<Item xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
<Name>My 3rd Item</Name>
<Type>Inventory</Type>
<IncomeAccountRef>66</IncomeAccountRef>
<ExpenseAccountRef>67</ExpenseAccountRef>
<AssetAccountRef>65</AssetAccountRef>
</Item>
```

This Fails to add the item as the last 3 fields below are missing from the xml output

```
$Item->setTrackQtyOnHand = ('true');
$Item->setQtyOnHand = ('10');
$Item->setInvStartDate = ('2015-01-01');
```

If I enter this code direct into the API explorer then the item is added to quickbooks as expected.

```
<Item xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
<Name>My 2nd Item</Name>
<Type>Inventory</Type>
<IncomeAccountRef>66</IncomeAccountRef>
<ExpenseAccountRef>67</ExpenseAccountRef>
<AssetAccountRef>65</AssetAccountRef>

<TrackQtyOnHand>true</TrackQtyOnHand>
<QtyOnHand>10</QtyOnHand>
<InvStartDate>2015-01-01</InvStartDate>
</Item>
```

I've looked through the sdk folder but I'm unsure where I to find the code that builds the xml output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of these are valid PHP ways to call a method:

```
$Item->setTrackQtyOnHand = ('true');        //MISSING FROM XML OUTPUT
$Item->setQtyOnHand = ('10');               //MISSING FROM XML OUTPUT
$Item->setInvStartDate = ('2015-01-01');    //MISSING FROM XML OUTPUT
```

A function call takes this format:

```
$Object->someMethod('value');
```

So your code should look like this:

```
$Item->setTrackQtyOnHand ('true');        //MISSING FROM XML OUTPUT
$Item->setQtyOnHand('10');               //MISSING FROM XML OUTPUT
$Item->setInvStartDate('2015-01-01');    //MISSING FROM XML OUTPUT
```

Please review the PHP syntax documentation:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Comment: Aaargh Copy & paste error! I didn't even notice them in there! Thanks very much for pointing this out! I notice your forums are down. Are there any plans to revive these?